# How much information does the multiplicative semigroup of an algebra contain?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, classification

How much do we know about an given algebra when we only know its semigroup strucure under the product law?

How far can two algebras be distinguished by knowing only their semigroup strucure?

The same question for rings, special categories of algebras, like *-algebras, Banach algebras, commutative algebras, etc.

Does anybody know results in this direction?

Comment: The question seems very vague. But one example to get you thinking might be that the underlying multiplicative semigroups of the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ and of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ are isomorphic, since after removing $0$ they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \times F$ where $F$ is a free abelian group on countably many generators.

Comment: There is a large literature on this but I forget the technical name for rings determined up to isomorphism by their multiplicative semigroups.

Comment: @Benjamin: Would be interesting to see some results. So the name.. My starting point was the category of C^*-algebras. Hard to imagine examples were one induces different additive structures on a given semigroup.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-01/S0002-9939-1958-0095868-0/S0002-9939-1958-0095868-0.pdf might be a start. I think that rings with unique addition is one name for rings determined up to iso by their multiplicative semigroup. Any semisimple artinian ring is such.

Comment: Some work in this direction was done by Yuri Samoilenko

Answer (score 3):

Gluskin [L. M. Gluskin, “Semigroups and rings of endomorphisms of linear spaces”, Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 23:6 (1959), 841–870 (Russian)] proved that rings of endomorphisms of vector spaces are defined by their multiplicative semigroups. In this paper also some useful information about other rings can be found. It seems there is a thranslation of this article into English.

**Addendum:** R. E. Peinado, On semigroups admitting ring structure.
Semigroup Forum, 1970, Vol.1, No.1, pp 189-208.

**One more addendum:** There are some papers in which one proved that topological spaces
are often determined by some subsemigroups of their semigroups of morphisms
[See: Gluskin, L.M.; Schein, B.M.; Shneperman, L.B.; Yaroker, I.S.
Addendum to ”A survey of semigroups of continuous selfmaps”. 
Semigroup Forum, v.14, pp.95-125 (1977)]. Would the spaces have *rings* of transformations, then those rings will be determined by semigroups. Of course, this is not a case. But maybe these ideas will be usefull for topological algebras.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed an interesting article with interesting clues. However, also quite special as the ring of *all* endomorphisms is considered. I would be especially interested in arbitrary subrings of such endomorphism rings.

Answer (score 1):

What also came into my mind is, that from matrix algebras of the form $A \otimes M_2$ we can recover the addition from the multiplication:

$$\left (\begin{array} 11 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right ) \left (\begin{array} aa & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{array} \right ) = \left (\begin{array} aa+b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$$